# In spring data jpa how can we save or update based on a non primary keys existence

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Can we save or update in spring data jpa based on a non primary key's existence,  as otherwise I have to check for existence using one query and check existence and then update.

Comment: Do you want to update the data without using the primary key?

Comment: I have two columns if the data while inserting is same then i have to update otherwise insert.

Answer (score 0):

I'll paraphrase your question in order to make sure that I got it right:

You start with an entity `e1` with an empty primary key.
The entity has among other properties two properties `(A, B)`.

If there exists already a persisted entity with the same values `(A, B)` you want to update that. 
Otherwise, you want to insert a row matching your entity `e1`.

The standard JPA way to do it would be:

1. query using `(A, B)`.
2. If you get an entity back grab the id, set it on `e1`. 
   Save `e1`.
3. If you don't get an entity back save `e1` as it is.

This, of course, does exactly the query you want to avoid.

Alternatively, you could do an update statement using an `@Query` annotation and check the update count.
If it is 0 just save `e1` as a new entity.

For this, you need to specify all the fields you want to update and it doesn't really work with cascading, i.e. with attributes that are entities themselves.

Answer (score -1):

As you have told that you want to Update or Save User based on non-primary Keys Below is the example of how you can do that with Jpa

Refer [Jpa Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

---

```
 public class User {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
    }
```

---

```
User user = userRepository.findByFirstnameAndLastname();
if(user==null)
{
    //Save New User
}
else
{
    //Update Your User
}
```

---

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE firstname = ?1 AND lastname = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
User findByFirstnameAndLastname(String firstName,String lastName);

//your Update Query
}
```

Comment: @vikram does this solves your query? This might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178929/how-can-i-prevent-insert-and-allow-only-update-of-my-object-using-spring-boot/55179444#55179444

Comment: This not solve the problem if update entity but not native query.